# Why does this code is not decreasing the value of hely?

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to make some checkboxes. 
If I check one of them, that one's counter should decrease by one (it has a space variable, so if someone checks that checkbox, it should decrease by one)
Also if they uncheck that, I would like to increase the space, so increase the space (hely) variable by one.
Now my code keeps increasing only, but it does not decreases.

(Sorry for the format of the code, but since stackoverflow made a new question asking page it is not that easy to copy my code like before...)

```js
var hely = 0;

function checkingFunction() {
  if (checkbox.checked == true) {
    hely--;
    change.innerHTML = hely;
  } else {
    hely++;
    change.innerHTML = hely;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Piarista Kollégium - Stúdiumi jelentkezés</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />

</head>

<body>

  <div class="topnav">

    <div class="topnav-centered">
      <a href="#home" class="active">Jelentkezés</a>
    </div>

    <a href="updates.html">Frissítések</a>

    <div class="topnav-right">
      <a href="login.html">Bejelentkezés</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="head">
    <img src="logo.png">
  </div>
  <h2>Üdvözöllek, XY!</h2>
  </div>


  <form class="checkbox" id="checkbox" action="">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>1.</th>
          <th>2.</th>
          <th>3.</th>
          <th>4.</th>
          <th>5.</th>
          <th>6.</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Hétfő</th>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="he1" onclick="checkingFunction()" name="hetfo"><label id="change" for="he1"> 
    </label></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="he2" onclick="checkingFunction()" name="hetfo"><label id="change" for="he2"> 
    </label></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="he3" onclick="checkingFunction()" name="hetfo"><label id="change" for="he3"> 
    </label></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="he4" onclick="checkingFunction()" name="hetfo"><label id="change" for="he4"> 
    </label></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="he5" onclick="checkingFunction()" name="hetfo"><label id="change" for="he5"></label>
          </td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="he6" onclick="checkingFunction()" name="hetfo"><label id="change" for="he6"> 
    </label></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Jelentkezés elküldése">
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If I check one checkbox, that one's counter should decrease by one (it has a space variable, so if someone checks that checkbox, it should decrease by one)
Also if they uncheck that, I would like to increase the space, so increase the space (hely) variable by one.

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make read and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance.

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique, you shouldn't have multiple `id="change"`.

Comment: Which one of them should be updated when you do `change.innerHTML = hely;`? Do you want a separate `hely` value for each checkbox? If you do that, it will just alternate between two values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple `id="change"` labels. When you do that, the variable `change` contains a collection of all of them, and assigning to `change.innerHTML` doesn't update any of them.

The variable `checkbox` refers to the `<form id="checkbox">`. Since forms don't have a `checked` property, `checkbox.checked == true` is never true, so `hely` always increments.

If you want to check the value of the box that the user checked, you need to pass it as a parameter to the function, using `onclick="checkingFunction(this)"`.

And if you want to update the label associated with that checkbox, you can use `checkbox.nextSiblingElement` to refer to it.

```js
var hely = 0;

function checkingFunction(checkbox) {
  var change = checkbox.nextElementSibling;
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    hely--;
  } else {
    hely++;
  }
  change.innerHTML = hely;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Piarista Kollégium - Stúdiumi jelentkezés</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />

</head>

<body>

  <div class="topnav">

    <div class="topnav-centered">
      <a href="#home" class="active">Jelentkezés</a>
    </div>

    <a href="updates.html">Frissítések</a>

    <div class="topnav-right">
      <a href="login.html">Bejelentkezés</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="head">
    <img src="logo.png">
  </div>
  <h2>Üdvözöllek, XY!</h2>
  </div>


  <form class="checkbox" id="checkbox" action="">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>1.</th>
          <th>2.</th>
          <th>3.</th>
          <th>4.</th>
          <th>5.</th>
          <th>6.</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Hétfő</th>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="he1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="hetfo"><label id="change" for="he1"> 
    </label></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="he2" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="hetfo"><label id="change" for="he2"> 
    </label></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="he3" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="hetfo"><label id="change" for="he3"> 
    </label></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="he4" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="hetfo"><label id="change" for="he4"> 
    </label></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="he5" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="hetfo"><label id="change" for="he5"></label>
          </td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="he6" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="hetfo"><label id="change" for="he6"> 
    </label></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Jelentkezés elküldése">
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```